# O que é Connection Keep-alive?

Tags: http, header, http-headers

Quando verifico os headers que estou enviando em uma página php, que está instalado localmente, sempre vejo esse `Connection: Keep-Alive`.

Exemplo:

```
var_dump(getallheaders());
```

Saída:

```
array (size=7)
  'Host' => string '127.0.0.1' (length=9)
  'User-Agent' => string 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0' (length=76)
  'Accept' => string 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' (length=63)
  'Accept-Language' => string 'pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3' (length=35)
  'Accept-Encoding' => string 'gzip, deflate' (length=13)
  'Cookie' => string '_ga=GA1.1.1775431020.1436189521' (length=31)
 
  'Connection' => string 'keep-alive' (length=10)
```

- O que significa `Keep-alive`?
- Pra que ele serve?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Uma conexão `Keep-Alive` significa uma conexão persistente, Ou uma conexão de vida persistente, entre o cliente e o servidor. Impedindo que a conexão se quebre de forma intermitente.

A conexão `HTTP` padrão geralmente é fechada após cada pedido tenha sido concluída, o que significa que o servidor fecha a conexão `TCP` após a entrega da resposta. 
A fim de manter a conexão aberta para várias solicitações, o cabeçalho de conexão `keep-alive` pode ser usado.

Na imagem fica claro como o keep alive funciona.

[image: Exemplo Keep Alive]

**Vantagens:**

- **Aumenta a velocidade do website:** Redução na latência em transferências HTTP.
- **Reduz uso da CPU:** Considere que o website tenha varias imagens, arquivos, será necessário uma conexão para cada arquivo, aumentando o uso da `CPU`, usando `keep-alive`, somente é feita uma conexão, assim reduzindo o uso da `CPU`.

**Desvantagens**

- **Aumenta o uso de memória:** Ativar o KeepAlive aumenta o uso de memória no servidor. Processos do Apache tem que manter conexões abertas à espera de novos pedidos de conexões estabelecidas.

Referências:

[W3](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.1/draft-ietf-http-v11-spec-01#Keep-Alive)
[MaxCDN](https://www.maxcdn.com/one/visual-glossary/keep-alive/)
[Varvy](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/keep-alive.html)
[Abdussamad](https://abdussamad.com/archives/169-Apache-optimization:-KeepAlive-On-or-Off.html)

Comment: Pelo texto explicativo do W3 (https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.1/draft-ietf-http-v11-spec-01#Connection) a imagem (não o texto) parece descrever incorretamente o comportamento. Ela da a ideia de que a forma de tráfego dos pacotes é diferente no caminho quando na verdade só existe uma redução de tempo no servidor por ele não fechar a conexão. Outra ideia errada na imagem é que da a entender que KeepAlive é um protocolo diferente do HTTP. O certo seria "Com KeepAlive" e "Sem KeepAlive".

Comment: Tomar a liberdade de editar a resposta alterando a legenda da imagem. Realmente passa a impressão que HTML e Keep Alive são protocolos distintos.

Comment: Vendo a imagem de exemplo fica bem mais fácil entender. +1 Por ela.

Comment: Um pequeno adendo, desde o HTTP/1.1 [conexões são persistentes por padrão](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7927599/664577), isso é, a não ser que o cliente seja HTTP/1.0 não há grandes motivos para enviar o *header* `Connection: keep-alive` para o servidor.